# change configuration of the context.xml file

Tags: tomcat, context.xml, server.xml

I have a file context.xml in the path /app/myapp/tomcat/conf/context.xml with this format:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/name-ds"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    username="username"
    password="password"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:port:SID"
    maxActive="100"
    maxIdle="20"
    initialSize="20"
    maxWait="30000"
    validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="7200" />

   <Resource name="jdbc/name2-ds"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    username="username"
    password="password"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:port:SID"
    maxActive="10"
    maxIdle="10"
    initialSize="10"
    maxWait="30000"
    validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="3600" />

  <Resource name="jdbc/name3-ds"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="username"
    password="password"
    driverClassName="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"
    url="jdbc:informix-sqli://IP:Port/dbname:informixserver=srv_name"
    removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
    validationQuery="select 1 from systables where tabid = 1"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="30"
    maxIdle="1" maxWaitMillis="10000"/>



    <Resource name="conf/app/properties"
                    auth="Container"
                    type="java.util.Properties"
                    factory="ma.glasnost.cjb.PropertiesObjectFactory"
                    path="/app/wassil.rct.ma/conf/property.properties"         />
```

where property.properties is in this format:

```
jdbc.dataSource=jdbc/name-ds
jdbc.ds1-dataSource=jdbc/name2-ds
jdbc.ds2-dataSource=jdbc/name3-ds
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
hibernate.default_schema=username
bootstrap.active=false
plsqlCall.active=false 
plsqlCreate.active=false
bootstrap.pays=pays
bootstrap.produit=false
bootstrap.qualifiers=
report.basePath=mypath
report.baseUrl=
liquibase.contexts=
batch.username=
batch.password=
ldap.server.url=
ldap.company.domain.name=
ldap.server.manager.dn=
ldap.server.manager.password=
ldap.server.domaine=
ldap.security.user.search.base=
ged.basePath=
ged.remoting.host=
ged.remoting.port=
ged.remoting.url=
mailServer.port=
mailServer.host=
```

And i want to consolidate all the variables in the property.properties file in the context.xml file to have only file where my variables are configured.How can I do this?
I m using tomcat-8.0.33 and java 8.0_73.

Comment: You definitely don't want to edit that file. You are defining database connections which will be created for *every application you deploy into the container* and not just the one you are looking at. Instead, edit `META-INF/context.xml` within the application and add those JNDI resources.

Comment: This depends entirely on the `ma.glasnost.cjb.PropertiesObjectFactory` class. Does it allow you to set properties directly on the factory, or do you have to use the `path` parameter to specify where the data comes from?